# Need to upload videos and auto embed onto my web app from YouTube

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, android-youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am getting an app made in MEAN and will have users registering and uploading images and videos on my app. So, if user "A" uploads a video, it should get saved in my YouTube channel and gets embedded on my web app under that user id with a YouTube player and thumbnail. Similarly, if user "B" uploads a video, it should get saved in the same YouTube channel and get embedded under his id. Is it possible to do so and if yes, kindly help me with it?

P.S. I don't want the users to upload the videos on YouTube under their respective ids.
Appreciate your help in advance. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you attempting something like this if "you're not a programmer"?